# GDAL in C++: Reading a ShapeFile

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr, c++, osx

I am trying to use the GDAL Lib to read a ShapeFile (.shp). I followed the instructions of http://www.gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html - But it doesn't work!

```
#include <gdal_priv.h>
#include <ogrsf_frmts.h>

int main()
{
GDALAllRegister();

GDALDataset       *poDS;   
poDS = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpenEx( "point.shp", GDAL_OF_VECTOR, NULL, NULL, NULL );
}
```

The error message is that "GDALOpenEx()" is a undeclared identifier. Also "GDAL_OF_VECTOR" is not declared.

How do I access the GDALOpenEx() method?
Do I have to load some drivers? (Which I thought GDALAllRegister() would do)

I am using xCode 6 on Mac OS 10.10. GDAL 1.11 from  http://www.kyngchaos.com/software:frameworks

Answer (score 5):

That solved my problem.

Further information and a tutorial can be found here http://gdal.org/1.11/ogr/ogr_apitut.html

A C++ version for GDAL 1.11:

```
#include <GDAL/ogrsf_frmts.h>
int main()
{
OGRRegisterAll();
OGRDataSource   *poDS;
poDS = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::Open( "data.shp", FALSE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [this](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#aca05455472359964151f9c891d678d5e) and [this](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#a8253249767721c3e54a4a2844b30f256), they say that both `GDALOpenEx()` and `GDAL_OF_VECTORS` were (will be?) introduced in GDAL 2.0.

GDAL 2.0 seems to be still under development. In case that you are able to compile it, you can find the source code [here](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/).

In older versions you would use [OGROpen](http://www.gdal.org/ogr__api_8h.html#a2da3630231780d519543d1679c83e62f) to read a Shapefile.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't find any information if GDAL 2.0 is stable, so I stick with 1.11. Although it is quite confusing, that the main website refers to GDAL 2.0. Did I miss something?

Comment: I agree, it's confusing. Don't know why they don't point to older versions easily, I wasn't able to find the link you put in your answer.

Comment: There is a reference to the 1.11.x API on the home page.  The main page is a product of the development version.  See:

http://gdal.org/1.11/index.html

for the 1.11 API

Comment: @kyle You're right, I couldn't see it yesterday. Thanks!